# iPhone Core Data Recursive Relationships

Tags: iphone, core-data, recursion, relationships

I'm having some trouble with a recursive relationship in core data.  I've got a managed object called a "SearchCategory", and that category can have "Categories" and it can also have a "Category."  In the managed object modeler, I've got two relationships set up on the SearchCategory entity, and both point back to the SearchCategory entity - one is named "Categories" and is a to-many relationship.  The other is "Category", is not a to-many, and is the inverse of "Categories."

In my code I'm using "setCategoriesObject" to add categories to a searchcategory, which seems to be working.  However, when I say `[mySearchCategory setCategory:aParentCategory]`, where `mySearchCategory` would be a child category of `aParentCategory`, it doesn't seem to want take in memory.  If I run the above code, then `[managedobjectcontext save:&err]`, it actually saves the primary key of the parent category to the "Category" field of the child category in the database, but Core Data doesn't synthesize this relationship at run time, so `[mySearchCategory Category]` returns nil.  Any thoughts here?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following you.  Every other words seems to be "category".  Can you add a screenshot of your model?  I think that would help.

Comment: ...and please show the code you're using and the exact string representation of the NSError you receive from `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]`.

Comment: Do you have your inverse relationships set up as true inverses? If you do then you will see one line only with cardinality arrows to indicate to-one or to-many. You really should post a screenshot of the datamodel.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was interpreting the results I was seeing incorrectly.  The relationship was in fact working properly, but the way I was looking at it made it seem that it wasn't.  Sorry for the bogus problem :(